# Two classes how to properly return values from class A to B

Tags: c#

I have two classes. First class takes user input as a string. User can choose for example: bananas, apples, grapes and blueberries.

```
class Choice
{
    string fruit;
    public void ChooseFruit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter [bananas] or [apples] or [grapes] or [bluebarries]");
        fruit = Console.ReadLine();
        ...
    }
}
```

Second class stores a variables for every fruit for examples if its banana (amount = 102.4, price = 12.34, volume = 16.3) different variables for every fruit.

How to return all the variables (amount, price, volume) to the first class for a chosen fruit in a proper way ?

[EDIT]
I tried something like this (it works but it doesnt look right):

```
class Choice
{
    string fruitName;
    float amount, price, volume;
    public void ChooseFruit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter [bananas] or [apples] or [grapes] or [bluebarries]");
        string fruitName = Console.ReadLine();

        Fruit f1 = new Fruit(fruitName);
        amount = f1.Amount;
        price = f1.Price;
        volume = f1.Volume;
        //...................//
    }
}
class Fruit
{
    public float Amount { get; private set; }
    public float Volume { get; private set; }
    public float Price { get; private set; }

    public Fruit(string name)
    {
        if (name.ToLower() == "bananas")
        {
            Amount = 12;
            Volume = 1.6f;
            Price = 27;
        }
        else if (name.ToLower() == "grapes")
        {
            Amount = 12;
            Volume = 1.6f;
            Price = 27;
        }
        // AND OTHERS //
    }
}
```

Comment: show that other class you're pertaining as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Aleksii. Please show us what you tried - even if it failed. Just your best attempt.

Comment: @Fildor  I edited post and pasted code.

Comment: Not too bad for a starter. Below you have two great answers you can draw inspiration from. Just a general tip: If dealing with monetary amounts, do not use floating point types (float, double). Use decimal instead, or else you'll soon have issues with rounding errors and / or unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation:

```
public enum Fruits {
    Bananas,
    Apples,
    Grapes,
    Blueberries
}

public class FruitInfo
{       
    public Fruits Fruit { get; }
    public decimal Price {get; set}
    ...   
}

// TODO: Populate this dictionary with all your fruit info
private Dictionary<Fruits , FruitInfo> _fruitDatabase;

public FruitInfo ChooseFruit()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose [bananas], [apples], [grapes], or [blueberries]: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        Fruits selection;

        if(!Enum<Fruits>.TryParse(input, true, out selection))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid Fruit Selection, Try Again.");
            continue;
        }

        return _fruitDatabase[selection];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want the community to solve your school assignments?

Anyway - try and have a look at

[Inheritance C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)

or even better

[Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

.. and see if you can make sense of it.

Good luck
/Anders

Comment: I'm not a student anymore. I try to learn C# through udemy/youtube and I simply have some doubts during writing code. I dont think that Inheritance and Polimorphism is what I'm looking for in this case.